# FQL query using stream table doesn't accept app access token

Tags: facebook, stream, cron, facebook-fql, access-token

I've searched stackoverflow all day long to find an answer without luck, so here we go.

I'm trying to fetch data from the stream table like this:

```
FQL: SELECT post_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 131559313586863
URL: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+post_id%2C+message%2C+created_time+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id+%3D+131559313586863&access_token=10669xxxxx74470|PF-7GSdBx0Nxxxxxkdi1KwSQG-w
```

But I get a 400 Bad Request as response with the error message: *"An access token is required to request this resource."*.

I'm fetching an application access token with this url: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID&client_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

Facebook state in [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/) that *"You will need to pass a valid app or user access token to access this functionality."*. Functionality refers to /feed and /posts (the stream table). Futhermore [this wiki](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL%3astream#Notes.2FBugs.2FGotchas) tells the same story about using the stream table, *"From June 3 2011 a token is required to query this table. You can use any application or user token to make the query."*.

**Does anyone see my hopefully obvious flaw?**

Please note:

- The profile in the FQL query is public.
- I need this to run userless though a cronjob. No user interaction is possible.
- The request works if I replace the app access token with my own user token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your app isn't set as 'desktop/native' in the app settings? if so, the app access token can't be used

Comment: Ohh my lord! It works after changing to the "Web" setting. Thank you so much. How did you know this?

Comment: I don't think it's well documented, but if the app is marked as native, it's assumed you distributed the app secret in the binary, and this it can't be trusted to make calls on behalf of the app (because users will have access to the secret and could then make calls on behalf of the app)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me – once I put in a valid access token **and** use HTTPS.

Comment: But did you use an *application* access token?

Comment: I'm using https. It endes up as http because I did not have enough reputation to post more than 2 links :-/

Comment: Works __perfectly__ using an __app__ access token …